# Rename/move multiple files with a file pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, move

I need to move any file matching a pattern defined by an `rsync` file pattern (used for `--include`, `--exclude`).

For example: `*.str`

I need to move any file in `/source/` to `/archive/` locally using Java. Will a simple `File.renameTo` method work? I don't see how looking at the source code.

What's the best way to do this? Any recommend libraries?

---

Background: some files and directories are being rsynced to multiple hosts. After it is successfully rsynced to each host, I need to archive the file (move it to the `archive` dir) locally. It works fine if local/source dir is a file, but when it's a directory and the rsync option `--include` is given, ONLY those files need to be moved after rsync is successful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ant move task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/move.html) programmatically. Get ant and use `org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Move`